# c# - how to compile folder with .cs files from a simple application

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-construction, compilation

I got my application for .NET 2.0. I want to use reflection for gathering classes information. But first I need to compile .cs files in folder. How can I do it **from my** application ? Its very important to do it automatically from my app. For example I want to have a method to which I can pass a path to a folder with .cs files and this method will compile all .cs files for me.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What's the end goal?

Comment: Draw a class diagram in Latex using informations such as class names,properties and fields collected using reflection ;). I want those informations to be writen in xml file so i can parse it and draw a class diagram using information from this xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.CodeDom;

public static Assembly CreateFromCSFiles(string pathName)
{
        CSharpCodeProvider csCompiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();

        CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
        compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;

        // here you must add all the references you need. 
        // I don't know whether you know all of them, but you have to get them
        // someway, otherwise it can't work

        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");
        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.Data.dll");
        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.Windows.Forms.dll");
        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.Drawing.dll");
        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.Xml.dll");

        DirectoryInfo csDir = new DirectoryInfo(pathName);
        FileInfo[] files = csDir.GetFiles();
        string[] csPaths = new string[files.Length];
        foreach (int i = 0; i < csPaths.Length; i++)
            csPaths[i] = files[i].FullName;
        CompilerResults result = csCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFile(compilerParams, csPaths);
        if (result.Errors.HasErrors)
            return null;
        return result.CompiledAssembly;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compile cs files both programmatically and from command-line.
To do it programmatically you need to use `CSharpCodeProvider` You can find more on the subject here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655